# Difference between visible and includeInLayout properties of a component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

Can anybody please tell me what about visible and includeInLayout properties of a component and what is the state of the component when they are in combination of {false,false},{false,true},{true,false}. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, `visible` is only about visibility of component and `includeInLayout` is only about taking part in process of component's laying out. Talking about laying out we're talking about such layouts as vertical layout, horizontal layout or tile layout where positions of the children determines by positions of other children.

Well, according to this explanation `false,false` is about target display object will not visible and will not affect on the position of other objects in layout. It is the same as target display object isn't exist at all.

The case `false,true` describes the situation where target display object isn't visible but takes part in layout. For end user it is an empty space between other objects in layout. This space has the same dimensions as our target display object.

The case `true,false` makes target display object visible but with not predictable position (depends on the particular layout implementation). Anyway it is not affect other elements position which laying out the way as target display object doesn't exist. It is very likely some of the other element overlap our target display obje